# What is Unchnga?

Tags: samsung, files, documents

I found a weird directory called .=UnchNGa

I deleted it via rar for android, otherwise I couldn't delete it. It was in my documents. What could it be? I didn't scan before I deleted it, but after Avira said everything is fine.

Edit for anyone wondering: It's faceapp.

Comment: Related: [Reddit - Weird directory showed up on my S20](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/1aicfvh/weird_directory_showed_up_on_my_s20/),